# Validating SQL Server stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a set of scripts that call stored procedures and would like to verify the parameters before invoking the procedure but I'm not finding the correct information.

In `usp_Add` shown below, `sys.parameters` reports that all of the parameters are nullable and none have default values. But this is not true. As shown in the left pane, `Process` and `Event` are required and have no default values while the rest do.

```
exec usp_Add 'Process', 'Event'
```

succeeds though my script flags it as invalid. How do I correct this query?

[image: Stored procedure parameters]

Thank you

Comment: There's no way to fetch default values for procedure parameters (unless it's clr proc) except for parsing procedure text, the system view "lies" because sql server doesn't track this information in metadata

Comment: That's discouraging.  How does the SSMS GUI know that the parameters have defaults?

Comment: It parses the procedure text? :) You can sorta fake it by calling the procedure with 1, 2, ... N parameters and see what happens but it's kinda painful. What do you need this validation for?

Comment: I'm going to replace throw with write-warning.  The module I'm writing will be used with lots of others and I'd like to flag errors as quickly as possible.  I'll have to limit this to a sanity check to ensure that the parameters passed are actually used by the stored procedure.   Thank you!